# PHP - PDF generator library with set expire function

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Does anyone know of a PHP PDF library (like FPDF) that has a function to set an expiry date on the generated file?  I am selling subscriptions to an online service that has a download as PDF component.  I would like to semi-secure the PDFs by having them expire after the subscription period.

Comment: big emphasis on the "semi", i hope, because this really doesn't do much security-wise at all

Comment: I included that for people like you :).  It doesn't have to be tough to beat as it just serves as a reminder to our trusted customers when it comes time to renew.  They may decide to "work around" whatever measures we deploy, however, we don't expect even a small percentage to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually - PDF supports JavaScript embedding, so maybe there's something like an annoying popup you could display whenever the time is right.

Link to Adobe site: [Adobe JavaScript embedding](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are servies which essentially add this as a wrapper around a PDF but nothing in the actual spec.